# Laravel 5: InvalidArgumentException in DateComparator.php line 38

Tags: php, laravel-5

I keep getting this error:

> Laravel 5: InvalidArgumentException in DateComparator.php line 38

If I refresh the page it will work fine: it only happens on the first load.

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
InvalidArgumentException in DateComparator.php line 38:
"now - 3.0E+12 seconds" is not a valid date.
in DateComparator.php line 38
at DateComparator->__construct('<= now - 3.0E+12 seconds') in Finder.php line 249
at Finder->date('<= now - 3.0E+12 seconds') in FileSessionHandler.php line 91
at FileSessionHandler->gc('3.0E+12') in StartSession.php line 150
at StartSession->collectGarbage(object(Store)) in StartSession.php line 70
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 118
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 86
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? You can start from https://github.com/illuminate/session/blob/master/Middleware/StartSession.php `collectGarbage` method, as 3.0E+12 is not valid date and it must come from somewhere in your application

Comment: What is the code that is at or above line 38?

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford , you've edited my post all wrong.
I get the error randomly. I can reload 5 times and get it only once. It can be the first load, or any other.

Comment: @manRo, I know that this date must have come from my app. I didn't understand how can I debug it?

Comment: @marklark, Line 38 is the "throw new" line :
    try {
               $date = new \DateTime($matches[2]);
               $target = $date->format('U');
           } catch (\Exception $e) {
               throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('"%s" is not a valid    date.', $matches[2]));
              }

Comment: @TzahiSerruya if you will take a look into [StartSession middleware line 193](https://github.com/illuminate/session/blob/master/Middleware/StartSession.php#L193) you will see that it takes date from `$this->manager->getSessionConfig()` which is `Illuminate\Session\SessionManager` injected into that object please check config file for your SessionManager class specially `lifetime` value

Comment: You are correct, that seems to be the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @TzahiSerruya apologies for misinterpretting your question.  it was unclear to begin with where the randomness occurred and where it went away. Know that you can go and re-edit your question to add or clarify information.

Comment: @NathanielFord Thank you, I didn't know I can.